# Ionic Framework - Web service ou Mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, web-service, ionic

Uma aplicação com Ionic Framework, pode acessar um banco de dados mysql igual uma aplicação web convencional? exemplo a hostnet. Ou é necessário um web service? E na questão de segurança,qual se destaca? 
O acesso será totalmente online, sem uso do SQlite

Comment: Pode ser acessado normal, estando hospedado em qualquer lugar (Hostnet, LocaWeb, Hostgator e etc). A unica questão é que precisa ser uma `API`, a questão de segurança, e bem proximo aos cuidados que precisa ter com `WEB`, use `JWT` que já vai dar uma ajuda legal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não, você não pode. Você precisar sim de um web service, que nesse caso será a camada que ficará encarregada da persistência dos seus dados.